# calculate frequency of unique values per group in R

Tags: r, count, logic, unique

How can I count the number of unique values such that I go from:

```
organisation <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D")
variable <- c("0","0","1","2","0","0","1","1","0","0","1","1","0","0","2","2")
df <- data.frame(organisation,variable)

organisation | variable
A            | 0
A            | 1
A            | 2
A            | 2
B            | 0
B            | 0
B            | 1
B            | 1
C            | 0
C            | 0
C            | 1
C            | 1
D            | 0
D            | 2
D            | 2
D            | 2
```

To:

```
unique_values | frequency
0,1,2         | 1
0,1           | 2
0,2           | 1
```

There are only 3 possible sequences:

- 0,1,2
- 0,1
- 0,2

Comment: So what about the first 4 lines. 0,1,2,2? Are you just trying to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM I am just interested in sequence of unique numbers, 0,1,2,2 ; 0,1,1,2 or 0,0,1,2 will give the same sequence 0,1,2. Same for 0,0,0,1 ; 0,1,1,1 -> 0,1 and 0,2,2,2 or 0,0,0,2 -> 0,2

Comment: Remove the duplicates.

Comment: Never mind. You would need to do that within grouping of ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s <- aggregate(. ~ organisation , data = df , \(x) names(table(x)))
s$variable <- sapply(s$variable , \(x) paste0(x , collapse = ","))
setNames(aggregate(. ~ variable , data = s , length) , c("unique_values" , "frequency"))
```

- output

```
  unique_values frequency
1           0,1         2
2         0,1,2         1
3           0,2         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

distinct(df) %>% 
  arrange(variable) %>%
  group_by(organisation) %>% 
  summarize(unique_values = str_c(variable,collapse = ",")) %>% 
  count(unique_values)
```

Output:

```
  unique_values     n
  <chr>         <int>
1 0,1               2
2 0,1,2             1
3 0,2               1
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang I get the following error message: Error in summarize(., unique_values = str_c(variable, collapse = ",")) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default